# Windows 8.1 couldn't be installed with error 0xc1900101 0x20006

Tags: windows-8.1

I tried to install the just released update of windows 8.1, but after several reboot it said it couldn't install it with the error :

```
windows 8.1 couldn't be installed with error 0xc1900101 0x20006
```

I don't have truecrypt or bitlocker, just a dual boot with MacOSx86 (hackintosh) and chimera bootloader, I am not sure if it has anything to do with the error.

Here is the interesting part of WindowsUpdate.log : http://pastebin.com/hxchfKii
And here is the full download and installation log : http://pastebin.com/A4NBLfuU

Thanks.

Comment: [This cat](https://www.facebook.com/Microsoft/posts/10151745103998721) recommends disabling your antivirus and unplugging any unnecessary USB devices.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of this cat : https://www.facebook.com/Microsoft/posts/10151745103998721
After unplugging a usb adaptor for Xbox 360 pad it worked.

Comment: Can you quote what it says? I don't have FB.